# What is the equivalent of "everything()" operator in "data.table"?

Tags: r, data.table

Let see the example:

```
 # 1. dplyr
 mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl, gear, everything())

 # 2. data.table
 as.data.table(mtcars)[, .(mpg, cyl, gear)]
```

What should be added after "gear" to have the same output as in "dplyr" case?

Thanks

Comment: `as.data.table(mtcars)[, c(c('mpg', 'cyl', 'gear'), setdiff(colnames(mtcars), c('mpg', 'cyl', 'gear'))), with = F]`

Answer (score 10):

Using *setcolorder*:

```
setcolorder(mtcars, neworder = c("mpg", "cyl", "gear"))
```

> **neworder**
>   Character vector of the new column name ordering. May also
>   be column numbers. If length(neworder) < length(x), the specified
>   columns are moved in order to the "front" of x. By default,
>   setcolorder without a specified neworder moves the key columns in
>   order to the "front" of x.